# Merging data tables of different lengths

Tags: r, data.table

I have six data tables of different lengths. They all have a common timeStamp column but different numbers of rows. I set the key for each to be the timeStamp column and then use the following line to merge them.

```
mergedDT = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), list(O3.official, eggNO2CO.1, eggNO2CO.2, eggNO2O3.1, eggNO2O3.2, eggPM))
```

The columns that don't have a corresponding row for a particular timeStamp contain `NaN`. I'd like this to be `NA`. Setting `all = FALSE` removes all rows that have a missing value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `all.x = TRUE`. This leaves all the rows in and sets the missing values to `NA`.